# modiagram referencial positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, modiagram

I've just recently discovered the modiagram package which is a big help, problem is that it only supports up to "p" orbitals whilst i need "d", i managed to do such by shifting \AO s, problem is that its exhaustive to keep thinking trying to manage the right separation and everything, so i remembered how tikz uses the positioning library to set relative positions for nodes, is there a way for us to set \AOs to work as d orbitals, referencing the position of the first and the rest by reference to each other?

here a tangible example:

```
% before begin document:
% 
% \usepackage{modiagram}        % Molecular orbital diagram
% \setmodiagram{names, labels, labels-fs=\tiny, AO-width=6mm}

\begin{modiagram}

    
    % left
    \AO( 5.0mm){s}[label=$x^2$-$y^2$]       { 0; }
    \AO(12.5mm){s}[label=$yz\phantom{^0}$]  { 0; }
    \AO(20.0mm){s}[label=$z^2$]             { 0; }
    \AO(27.5mm){s}[label=$xz\phantom{^0}$]  { 0; }
    \AO(35.0mm){s}[label=$xy\phantom{^0}$]  { 0; }
    
    \node at (20.0mm, -1) 
    {\tiny Ausencia de campo exterior};
    
    % middle    
    \AO(50.0mm){s}{1; }
    \AO(57.5mm){s}{1; }
    \AO(65.0mm){s}{1; }
    \AO(72.5mm){s}{1; }
    \AO(80.0mm){s}{1; }
    
    \node at (65.0mm,-1)
    {\tiny Campo Esférico};
    
    % right below
    \AO( 95.0mm){s}[label=$yz$]{ .4; }
    \AO(102.5mm){s}[label=$xz$]{ .4; }
    \AO(110.0mm){s}[label=$xy$]{ .4; }
    
    % right above
    \AO(102.5mm){s}[label=$x^2$-$y^2$]  {1.6; }
    \AO(110.0mm){s}[label=$z^2$]        {1.6; }
    
    \node at (102.5mm, -1) 
    {\tiny Campo Octaédrico};
    
    \draw[<->] 
    (90mm,1.6)
    -- node[left]{\tiny $0.6\,\Delta_{\text{oct}}$} 
    (90mm,1.0);
    
    \draw[<->]
    (90mm,1.0)
    -- node[left]{\tiny $0.4\,\Delta_{\text{oct}}$}
    (90mm,0.4);
    
    \draw[<->]
    (120mm,1.6) node[left]{\tiny e\textsubscript{g}}
    -- node[right]{\tiny $\Delta_{\text{oct}}$}
    (120mm,0.4) node[left]{\tiny t\textsubscript{2g}};
    
    \connect{AO5 & AO6, AO10 & AO11, AO10 & AO14}
    
    \EnergyAxis
    \node at (0,1)[above, rotate=90]{\tiny Energia};

\end{modiagram}
```

what i want is something like this

```
\begin{modiagram}
%[names, labels, labels-fs=\tiny, AO-width=6mm]
    
    % left
    \AO( 5.0mm){s}[label=$x^2$-$y^2$]               { 0; }
    \AO(right=of AO1){s}[label=$yz\phantom{^0}$]    { 0; }
    \AO(right=of AO2){s}[label=$z^2$]               { 0; }
    \AO(right=of AO3){s}[label=$xz\phantom{^0}$]    { 0; }
    \AO(right=of AO4){s}[label=$xy\phantom{^0}$]    { 0; }
.
.
.
.
```

any suggestions on how to do something similar?